# Sequential Ajax Calls fail in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, upload

I've looked at multiple solutions to this problem but nothing's working to fix my problem.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.5.

Here are my steps:

1. Use ajax call in page to upload file.
2. Within same function that generates ajax call run an ajax call to refresh the page to include the uploaded file, after ajax call is finished.

I'm using this as the first call (to upload) (compliments of another Stack Overflow user):

```
function uploadFiles() {

    document.getElementById('fileupload').onsubmit = function () {
        var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('uploadfilenames');
        //Iterating through each files selected in fileInput
        for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
            //Appending each file to FormData object
            formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
        }
        //Creating an XMLHttpRequest and sending
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/Dashboard/UploadFiles');
        xhr.send(formdata);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                //alert(xhr.responseText);  
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    reloadMain();
}
```

The `reloadMain()` function is:

```
function reloadMain() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Dashboard/ThumbList/' + currentPath,
        type: "GET",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#thumb-list").html(msg)
        },
        error: displayError("Unable to get file listing")
    });
}
```

I have noticed this:

1. The 'refresh' doesn't include the uploaded file information in the response
2. IE11 and Chrome act differently.
3. It seems that the problem is that the controller/system doesn't complete the file operations soon enough (I saw a "denied access...file in use" error when using Chrome.

So, it would seem that the refresh ajax call needs to wait until the file system completes its work.

Would you agree? If so, how can I make this work?

Comment: you need to set first ajax call async to false, so that it will send the 2nd ajax call after first completes

Answer (score 0):

You can either set your XMLHttpRequest async to false:

```
xhr.open('POST', '/Dashboard/UploadFiles', false);
```

Or you can call your refresh function in callback:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/Dashboard/UploadFiles');
xhr.send(formdata);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
       reloadMain(); //Only refresh after the file post get a 200 response
   }
}
```